# call & apply method

Tags: javascript, methods, call

I am a beginner trying to figure this coding thing out. 
I can't get this to logout right. Can you spot the problem?

In the console.log line within the string, starting at the $-sign the code doesn't change color, so it doesn't recognize it. Thanks.

```
const car2 = {
  brand: "Porsche", 
  getCarDescription: function(cost, year, color) {
    console.log("This car is a ${this.brand}.  The price is $${cost}.  The year is ${year}. The color is ${color}.\n");
  }
};

car2.getCarDescription(90000, 2013, "red");
```

> This car is a ${this.brand}.  The price is $${cost}.  The year is ${year}. The color is ${color}.
>
> => undefined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Template literals are surrounded by backticks, not double quotes.

Comment: for this type of string concatenation use the back-tick ( ` ) instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const car2 = { brand: "Porsche", getCarDescription: function(cost, year, color) 
{ 
console.log(`This car is a ${this.brand}. The price is $${cost}. The year is ${year}. The color is ${color}.\n`); }
 }; 
car2.getCarDescription(90000, 2013, "red");
```

You need to use `` instead of "" for using ${}

Just go through following document for more details [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals](http://Template%20literals)